# Where to start with an online table booking system?

Tags: html, web-applications, frontend, backend

So I want to create an online booking system for reserving tables at restaurants for a personal project, but I have no clue where to start. I don't know what language to use, what to do with the tables in MySQL or anything for that matter.
Any pointers would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: First step should be: making a proper research and this does not happen on SO but search engines

Comment: @B001 I have been through about 15 pages on google, all I can see is other peoples software, whereas I want to build my own, not use someone elses

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* the immediate answer you are looking for but I'll give you some pointers base on my experience and the different situations you might be in:

- Treat this as a product: Define exactly what you need (if you have, we can help you best if you tell us about it). What is your main goal, what are the features you/the client need, think about the different type of users, build a road map for the whole UX, wireframe each step of the map, prototype, test. Programming-wise, stick to your guns. For example, if you know Rails and mySQL, use that. Do you know something else? Use that then, don't even think about it.
- Don't reinvent the wheel, if there is a clear and accessible (read in-budget) option don't rule it out just because. Googled "table reservation software" and randomly picked one (tablein) and it's awesome and the pricing seemed alright to be fair.
- If this is purely educational then go nuts. I would suggest following the steps from the first bullet-point and then picking a language you would like to learn or get better at.

All of this is common place for developers. Coming up with an idea just to learn something new, implementing some alien technology to your own code, or creating thing entirely from scratch.